# SELECTion Considering Subsets of Parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have the following table `Orders`, with columns:

- `order_id`,
- `timestamp`,
- `worker_id`,
- `costumer_id`,
- `start_ts`,
- `end_ts`

What is the best way to query the database according to any combination of `start_ts`, `end_ts`, `worker_id` and `costumer_id`?

If `start_ts` is omitted I would:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Orders
  WHERE timestamp <= end_ts
    AND worker_id = <worker_id>
    AND costumer_id = <costumer_id>;
```

If `worker_id` and `costumer_id` are omitted instead:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Orders
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN start_ts AND end_ts;
```

Comment: The only way this matters is per the indexes defined on the columns. For indexes that contain more than one field, the fields in the where clause should be listed in the same order as they are defined in the index.  It helps with performance but is not illegal syntax to use a different order.

Comment: @jdl134679 Good comment, altough this isnt the scope of the question, im really looking for SQL features for dealing with such scenarios

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple conditions like so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE (timestamp >= <start_ts> or <start_ts> is null)
    AND (timestamp <= <end_ts> or <end_ts> is null)
    AND ... ;
```

Where `...` represents as many `WHERE` conditions, combined using `AND`, as you like.

Comment: how do you suggest on doing that? stored procedure?

Comment: @OfekRon, can be a proc with parameters. Just pass null to params where you want to omit.

Comment: Maybe my example was too simple, but what if you can ommit a join with a table if a parameter is ommited?